# How can I do a 'where' clause in Linux shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a CSV file and I would like to filter all the lines where the 19th column has two or more characters.  I know the individual pieces but can't figure out how to glue them together.  First I have to cat the file.  The following prints the 19th column

```
awk -F "," '{print $19}' file.txt
```

awk also has length and ifs

And I know it all has to be glued together using pipes.  I'm just getting stuck at the exact syntax since I have not done much bash programming before.

Comment: Note that `awk -F,` is not sufficient to parse a CSV. Consider `"Hi, World",1337`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An `AWK` program is a series of pattern action pairs, written as:

```
condition { action }
```

The `condition` part is your filter.

For example, to get all lines(19th column has at least 2 chars):

```
$ awk -F, 'length($19)>1' file.txt
```

When `{action}` part is missing, the default action is to print the record.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
awk -F ',' '{if (length($19) < 2) { print $0 }}' file.txt
```

It prints the whole line if the length of the 19th field is smaller than 2.

Comment: Because `print` is the default action, the script can be simply `awk -F, 'length($19)<2' file.txt`